# Not receiving the email of grep output after bash command is run

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the code below, it does not send the grep output to email but it shows the output command line. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
sudo tail -f  /path/to/file | while read line ; do 
    egrep 'successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components|successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components' 
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        (echo " RESTARTS"; echo; echo $line) | mail -s "RESTART" email@email.com
    else
        echo " FAILS"
    fi
done
```

[UPDATE]

There is another way I was trying to do this but it wont send email..I was just making sure that I can break out of loop and not go forever and so thats why I put the tail in while

```
while read line; do

    echo "$line" | sudo tail -f  /opt/bmc/ao/cdp/tomcat/logs/grid.log

    if [ $(echo "$line" | grep -E 'successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components|successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components' | wc -l) -ne 0 ]; then
        (echo "CDP RESTARTS"; echo; echo "$line") | mail -s "BAOCDP AUTO RESTART" noreply@google.com

        break
    fi

done
```

Comment: Take the ( out of the script

Comment: OK. I will try that.

Comment: @RamanSailopal That won't work, only the `echo $line` would be piped into `mail`, while the two previous echos would go into stdout

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will add $line and run the script again.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't see the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` can't guess that you want it to work on the content of the `$line` variable, you have to provide it to the command :

```
egrep 'successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components|successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components' <<< "$line"
```

or

```
echo "$line" | egrep 'successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components|successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components'
```

Concerning your edit, I'd go with the following code :

```
sudo tail -f  /opt/bmc/ao/cdp/tomcat/logs/grid.log | while read line; do

    if $(echo "$line" | grep -E 'successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components|successfully started \[[0-9] out of [0-9]\] components'); then
        (echo "CDP RESTARTS"; echo; echo "$line") | mail -s "BAOCDP AUTO RESTART" noreply@google.com

        break
    fi

done
```

Aside from putting back the `tail` where it belongs, I also simplified the `if`'s condition : `grep` will return 1 if and only if it matches, so it can be used as the condition itself.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to use the $line and run the script again.

Comment: @H.Birdi Another point : it looks like your script will run forever, displaying "FAIL" for every single new line of the file that doesn't match the regex, which sounds awful. You might want to exit once the mail has been set (if the script only has to run until the server is started) or remove the `echo "FAIL"` (if the script is meant to run in the background forever, sending mail each time the server starts)

Comment: I have failure option because if it doesn't match the components started then it will say it fails...is there another way to do it? should I put EXIT 0 after the mail has been sent?

Comment: @H.Birdi I guess your script will have to read a few lines before the one that says the start has been successful. On these lines, you obviously don't want to send a mail, but is it relevant to print FAIL for each of these lines? Reading 50 FAIL lines before my mail is sent would quickly annoy me. Moreover you have no stopping condition on your loop, because `tail -f` is made to never reach the end of the file, but rather wait for eventual new content. You will want to exit somehow (`exit 0` or the equivalent `exit` would be fine) unless you want your script to run forever

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It no relevant to read print FAIL for these lines. I don't care about those line. Only the grep string, which is two lines. I'm new to bash. I will be using cranjob to run this script every sunday to restart this server. I just want to server to restart automatically and if the components doesn't match it will send the email that CDP fail. It not gonna run forever only run when server is started then find the grep string send the email..

Comment: @H.Birdi No problem ; you might want to check out https://www.shellcheck.net which will proofread your scripts. Also since your script is run by `cron`, your `echo FAIL` won't be output anywhere unless otherwise specified, so I would remove it once the script has been tested ; until then it's a good indicator that a line has been read but didn't match. You might want to make sure that your script will eventually end, even if it never matches the expected line (and that would be a good opportunity to send a warning email) ; the `timeout` command might help

Comment: Thanks for help. I will use all your suggestion to fix this script. Thanks once again.

Comment: @H.Birdi you're welcome ! Please accept my answer since it solved your problem, this is the best way to show gratitude around here ;)

Comment: Please grep from `"$line"` (in quotes).

Comment: I did change that.

Comment: I just posted the update about another code. Can any of you guys explain why this one is not sending the email?

Comment: @H.Birdi just so you know, I'm the only one notified of your comment, and it's unlikely a question with an accepted answer will receive much attention. Next time you'd better post another question, but I'll check your code :)

Comment: @H.Birdi yeah just put back the tail "outside" of the loop, it will be stopped once you `break` (because `while` being `break`ed of will close the pipe, which `tail` will notice and stop). Also the `echo something | tail -f someFile` doesn't make sense, if `tail` is following a file it won't use its standard input provided through the pipe. Otherwise it seems good

Comment: @H.Birdi your regex also seems redundant, unless you made a copy paste error it's an alternation between two repetitions of the same pattern, you can probably remove the `|` and what follows

Comment: Will it stop the tail -f?

Comment: My regex is fine..they both are similar line with different numbers

Comment: @H.Birdi it will stop the `tail -f`. Concerning the regex, the first part of the alternation would match both lines, since `[0-9]` will match any number (which does not have to be the same number each time the regex matches) ; check [this](https://regex101.com/r/ip9YXq/1) out.

Comment: Thanks for the help Aaron. It means a lot. Thanks once again.

Comment: I will try to fix the regex part. In the log, they have two line - successfully started 5 out 5 components and successfully started 9 out 9 components. So, when it find these lines,  send to the email and stop the tail..That was my whole thought process

Comment: @H.Birdi the problem is that for now `grep` is going to match the first line and return success, it won't wait for the second one. It wouldn't be easy to do otherwise with `grep` (because it's a line based tool), so you should either use 2 distinct `grep`s with their specific expected number, or have a counter of the time the generic `grep` succeeded (which would be better if you expect these numbers to change in the future)

Comment: How do I do the counter option? Sorry I m new to bash..I do expect these numbers to change

Comment: @H.Birdi you initialise a variable to 0 outside of the loop, then you increment it inside the loop each time `grep` matches. Once `grep` has matched the required amount of time you send your mail and `break` out of the loop. You might want to pick up a quick `bash` tutorial, it might end up faster than waiting for me to answer each time ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate it.